# how to use laravel blade directives for api

Tags: php, angular, laravel, laravel-5

i want to use angular and laravel for our project in that i am using spatie library i want to know that is there any way that you can use laravel blade directives like i want to use @hasrole , @role etc in blade or do you know how to use any other blade directives like @if, @foreach i know you can manage it in the angular but my main doubt is about how to use spatie @hasrole, @role etc for api's please tell me if you hit with any idea 
its like

```
 @role('individual')
      <h5>Only individual can see this </h5>
 @endrole
 @role('agent')
      <h5>Only agent can see this</h5>
 @endrole
```

i want to all this functionality on api any suggestions?

Comment: Could you not write on the user model a function that determines what role they are? then you could do something like `@if($user->isAgent())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to use Laravel Blade **and** Angular in your project?
If so, I would advice to not use Laravel Blade at all to render HTML since Angular is doing it.
Laravel, with Blade, is a backend and frontend framework, which means that it is able to compute and render the pages. Angular is only frontend: it uses data received from a remote source to build its pages. To put it in a nutshell, in my opinion, using Laravel with Blade and Angular besides is counterproductive.

**But**, if you only want to use annotations like you can find in Laravel Blade but in Angular, you can't. Angular, as I said, is decorrelated from the backend, it uses only data received to render the HTML. By this, I mean that you have two parties: Laravel (backend) and Angular (frontend). Angular need to have access to a variable which contains the role. There is many way to accomplish this ([JWT](https://jwt.io/) for example).
If I assume that you succeed to have the role somewhere in your Angular app, you can control the view like this:

```
<h5 ng-if="role === 'individual'">
    ...
</h5>
<h5 ng-if="role === 'agent'">
    ...
</h5>
```

You can see the Angular documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf). There is another directive that is used the same way but have a different behaviour: [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).

For further help, I found an article that can show you how to communicate between Laravel and Angular using tokens: https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps

Comment: amazing very well explanation, cleared my all doubts really nice paul, very helpfull